# Converting a full date into just hours and minutes - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I'm trying to do something very simple here and failing miserably. I just want to convert a string with a complete date into just the hours and minutes, can anyone see where I am going wrong? The following code prints nil

```
let dateString2 = "2018-03-11 20:43:05 +0000"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss +zzzz"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")


let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString2)

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
print("Dateobj: \(dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!))")
```

Comment: That code actually crashes for me in Xcode 9.2, on the last line, due to the nil dateObj.

Answer (score 7):

Your `dateFormat` String is flawed. `hh` is the 12hour time format, when you clearly receive a 24h time format, for which you need to use `HH`. Even though `zzzz` works, +0000 should actually be represented by `z`. When working with fixed time formats in most cases you should also set the `locale` to `en_US_POSIX`.

```
let dateString2 = "2018-03-11 20:43:05 +0000"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString2)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
print("Dateobj: \(dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!))")
```

Output:

> 20:43

Comment: The output will depend on the user's timezone. You will only get `20:43` if being run in a timezone with the same offset as UTC. Using `+zzzz` is far from ideal. It works for this string but it should not be used in general`.

Comment: Setting the timezone is most likely inappropriate here. 1) It will be ignored when converting the original string since the string provides its own timezone information. 2) It's likely that the final result should be in local time, not UTC time. Only set a specific timezone if the desired output needs to be in that specific timezone.

Answer (score 4):

You need `HH` (24-hour) for the hour, not `hh` (12-hour). You also need to use the special locale of `en_US_POSIX`, not `en_GB`. You should also use `Z` for the timezone, not `+zzzz`.

```
let dateString2 = "2018-03-11 20:43:05 +0000"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")


if let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString2) {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm" // or "hh:mm a"
    print("Dateobj: \(dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj))")
}
```